# In-app billing. If user closes the application while the Payments Successful dialog is not closed

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment, billing

While the Payments Successful dialog is not closed, the user closes the application, as a result, the money is withdrawn and Google considers the transaction USER_CANCELED how to make it work even if the user kills the application ?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

private MyPresenter presenter;
boolean needUpdateCoins = false;
private BillingClient mBillingClient;
private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap;

private static final String 1_SKU_ID = "1";
private static final String 2_SKU_ID = "2";

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        presenter = new MyPresenter(this);
        initBillingClient();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Myfragment, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
        return view;
    }

private void initBillingClient(){ 
mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(getActivity())
.enablePendingPurchases().setListener((billingResult, purchases) -> {
            if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                for(Purchase purchase:purchases){
                    handlePurchase(purchase);
                }
            }
        }).build();

        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    querySkuDetails();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {}
        });
    }

private void querySkuDetails() {
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(1_SKU_ID);
        skuList.add(2_SKU_ID);
        skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), (billingResult, skuDetailsList) -> {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                    mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                }
            }
        });
    }
 void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
                ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                        .setDeveloperPayload(purchase.getDeveloperPayload())
                        .build();
                ConsumeResponseListener consumeResponseListener = (billingResult, purchaseToken) -> {
                    if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                        payComplete(purchase.getOrderId(), purchase.getPackageName(), purchase.getSku(), purchase.getPurchaseTime(), purchase.getPurchaseState(), purchase.getPurchaseToken());
                    }
                };
                mBillingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, consumeResponseListener);
            }
        }
    }
   public void launchBilling(String skuId) {
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(skuId))
                .build();
         mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(getActivity(), billingFlowParams);
    }
   @Override
    public void coinPackClick(CoinPack pack) {
        String skuId = String.valueOf(pack.getId());
        launchBilling(skuId);
    }

private void payComplete(String orderId, String packageName, String productId, Long purchaseTime, int purchaseState, String purchaseToken){
 presenter.buyCoin(orderId, packageName, productId, purchaseTime, purchaseState, purchaseToken);
    }
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Tell me, do you have any thoughts or opinions looking at this code?

Comment: Read this tutorial carefully https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview